# System.InvalidOperationException: 'Can't add a binding rule since it is missing the/a BindingAttribute' for .net 8 isolated Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-8.0, azure-functions-isolated

Overall, I want to create the user-object from the BearerToken in the Http-Header. I want the property to get auto populated. If there is any other/better way to do so, I am open for it.

I am currently trying to figure out how to "inject" a value to an azure function attribute using the InputBindingAttribute. But I get an exception when adding the binding rule.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config;


public class MyBinding : InputBindingAttribute
{
    
}

public class BindExtension : IExtensionConfigProvider
{
    public void Initialize(ExtensionConfigContext context)
    {
        //System.InvalidOperationException: 'Can't add a binding rule for 'MyBinding' since it is missing the a BindingAttribute'
        context.AddBindingRule<MyBinding>().BindToInput(_ => new User(new("id"), "Bob"));
    }
}
```

```
public class TestFunction
{
    private readonly ILogger<TestFunction> _logger;

    public TestFunction(ILogger<TestFunction> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Function("TestFunction")]
    public Task Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req, [MyBinding] User user)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Any advice?

I tried to follow https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Creating-custom-input-and-output-bindings as guidance.